# Using multiple case is <>

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning, afternoon to everyone:

I've a statement in VBA like this one:

```
Select Case MAAX(Fila, 1)
    Case Is <> 5, Is <> 10, Is <> 15, Is <> 20, Is <> 25, Is <> 30, Is <> 35, Is <> 40
            Do whatever
End Select
```

But it's not working..What is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Perhaps your understanding of the logic of that statement is incorrect. Your statement will effectively evaluate to `TRUE`

Comment: In future, please explain why it's not working. Give us some example data which hasn't worked and explain what it would look like if it had worked

Comment: I'm sorry Ron and CallumDA, I forgot explain the problem from my point of view.. If the fist number evaluated is 10, the statement is true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "not working" you mean that the statement following your `CASE` is always being executed, you may be misinterpreting how that statement works:

> If testexpression matches **ANY** Case expressionlist expression, the statements following that Case clause are executed ...

Almost no matter what is in `MAAX(Fila, 1)`, it will surely match at least one of your clauses.

You'll need to rewrite your CASE statement (or use something else), to test for the logic you really want.

If, what you really want, is that your testvalue is not any of those (5, 10, ...), you could do something like

```
if v<>5 and v<>10 and v<>15 ...
```

or, possibly

```
 select case v mod 5
     case is <>0  'then it is not one of those in your list, 
                  'but it could be greater than 40, so you might have to test for that
```

Comment: So, in this type of expression, if the first case is TRUE, everything else doesn't mind....

Comment: @Manuel Regard your `Case` statement as having the `test_expressions` connected by `OR`'s.  So if any one of the `test_expressions` is true, the line following will execute.

Comment: I will do. Thanks a lot for your answer, Ron

Answer (score 1):

See Ron's answer for a good explanation of the probem. I'd personally change your code to this:

```
Select Case MAAX(Fila, 1)
    Case 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40
    Case Else
        'do something
End Select
```